# ListView items disappearing on touch or click on custom webview

Tags: listview, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

I am creating an UWP app through Xamarin PCL. In my page I have a listview and a native uwp webview(which is rendered through custom renderer) inside another stack layout.

**My problem is**:-
When I am running the app in windows laptop which is having touchscreen, the list items items which are currently shown on screen, disappears on clicking or touching anywhere on the webview container. Click or touch at any other location doesn't affect the list.

However list items are present in the list itemssource as clicking on any item cell, app is working as expected. In emulator app is working fine.

I have checked with the long list data, in this case, only the items which are currently in view are disappearing while other items are shown properly as I can see them on scrolling down.

Please Suggest any solution.

View

```
public class NativeWebView : View
{
    public NativeWebView()
    {
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       propertyName: "Uri",
       returnType: typeof(string),
       declaringType: typeof(NativeWebView),
       defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

CustomRenderer For webview

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
```

namespace XYZ

{

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<NativeWebView, WebView>

{

    static WebView webView;

    public CustomWebViewRenderer()
    {            
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NativeWebView> e)
    {

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(new WebView());
            webView = Control;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Content//{0}", Element.Uri));
        }
    }
```

}

Xaml.cs

```
public ClassName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NativeWebView nativeWebView = new NativeWebView();
        nativeWebView.Uri = "index.html";
        nativeWebView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        nativeWebView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        myStackLayout.Children.Add(nativeWebView);

        this.viewModel = new PersonViewModel();

        this.BindingContext = this.viewModel;

        this.LoadItems(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void LoadItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listView.ItemsSource = this.viewModel.PersonItems;
    }
```

Xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="80">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="2,15">
                                    <Label Text ="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"></Label>
                                    <Label Text ="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="20, 0, 0, 10"></Label>
                                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="190" HorizontalOptions="Start"  BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20, 0, 0, 10" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="0"  >
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: please provide xaml and binding code

Comment: I have updated the code please have a look and tell me if you want any other detail.

Comment: can you share sample project somewhere so we don't need to recreate the project? Also UWP has build in WebViewRenderer. have you tried to use it?

Comment: Please take the sample project from the below link https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zsmdugjdn08u39/ListViewDisappearingApp.rar?dl=0

Comment: I suggest you to create a bug with this sample in xamarin bugzilla and post the link here too. I would like to subscribe to it. This happens in UWP only and I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: BTW, it has nothing to do with your renderer. If I just add WebView to page and point it for example to google that happens too

Comment: I have raised a bug on xamarin bugzilla. Link of the bug is:-
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59307

Comment: I restarted VS2017, clean, rebuild and it works now. Very strange

Comment: Bug is resolved in latest pre-release.